# What does this warning mean in C++ for exception handling?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have written a code for exception handling for division operation:
I had include the `Zero division error`, `Negative value error` (Not an exception but I included it!) and `Indeterminate form error` (I included it also).

Then after compilation it shows some warnings, but the `.exe` file is running as expected.
Here is the code and the output which I receive after compilation.

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int numerator, denominator, quotient, remainder;
    cout << "Enter the value of numerator and denominator: ";
    cin >> numerator >> denominator;
    try
    {
        if (!numerator && !denominator)
        {
            throw logic_error("Logical Error: Indeterminate Form!\n");
        }
        else if (!denominator)
        {
            throw runtime_error("Math Error: Attemp to divide by zero!\n");
        }

        else if (numerator < 0 || denominator < 0)
        {
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid Arguments: Negative numbers not allowed!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            quotient = numerator / denominator;
            remainder = numerator % denominator;
            cout << "The result after division is:\n"
                 << "Quotient: " << quotient << "\nRemainder: " << remainder << '\n';
        }
    }
    catch (logic_error &exc)
    {
        cout << exc.what();
    }
    catch (runtime_error &exc)
    {
        cout << exc.what();
    }
    catch (invalid_argument &exc)
    {
        cout << exc.what();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "Some Exception Occured!\n";
    }

    cout << "\nProgram Finished...\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Exceptional_Handling_05.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Exceptional_Handling_05.cpp:42:5: warning: exception of type 'std::invalid_argument' will be caught
   42 |     catch (invalid_argument &exc)
      |     ^~~~~
Exceptional_Handling_05.cpp:34:5: warning:    by earlier handler for 'std::logic_error'
   34 |     catch (logic_error &exc)
      |     ^~~~~
Enter the value of numerator and denominator: 52 0
Math Error: Attemp to divide by zero!

Program Finished...
```

What does this warning mean here?
Although the output of the program is as expected for every corner and exceptional cases.

Comment: the error message is actually quite clear. You don't need the catch for `invalid_argument` because it inherits from `logic_error`, hence is already catched. Add some `std::cout` or similar in the `catch (invalid_argument &exc)` to see that it will never be triggered

Comment: btw, try to use exceptions sparingly, for exceptional cases, not for control flow. A user typing wrong input isnt that exceptional. You could print the message right at the place where you check the condition as well. However, I guess this is an exercise on exceptions so removing them would be rather pointless

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes, I am learning exception handling in C++ right now. This is not a program which should be made, I am only practicing.

Comment: its not called "exceptional handling" btw

Comment: Ohh ok, thanks for editing :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A stripped down version of your code that triggers the same warning is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    int numerator = -1, denominator = -1;
    try
    {        
        if (numerator < 0 || denominator < 0)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Arguments: Negative numbers not allowed!\n");
        }
    }
    catch (std::logic_error &exc)
    {
        std::cout << exc.what();
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument &exc)
    {
        std::cout << " THIS IS NEVER REACHED !!";
        std::cout << exc.what();
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Invalid Arguments: Negative numbers not allowed!
```

Because `std::invalid_argument` inherits from `std::logic_error` and the exception is already handleded by the first `catch`.  If you want to catch both seperately, the general `logic_error` and the more specialized `invalid_argument`, you need to do it in opposite order:

```
catch (std::invalid_argument &exc)
{
    std::cout << exc.what();
}
catch (std::logic_error &exc)
{
    std::cout << exc.what();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `invalid_argument` is derived from `logic_error` and the codes are executed from up to down. It is meant the exception will be caught by the `logic_error` first. The `invalid_argument` is redundant and could be removed